# Is there a way to run raw sql with Kotlin's Exposed library

Tags: sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I'm trying to run some sql specific to postgres and would like to reuse the transaction management within Exposed.

Answer (score 15):

Exposed has the `Transaction.exec(String)` method which probably does what you want. See https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/blob/master/exposed-tests/src/test/kotlin/org/jetbrains/exposed/sql/tests/mysql/MysqlTests.kt

Answer (score 11):

With help from Kiskae's answer, I was able to run the raw sql with:

```
transaction {
     val conn = TransactionManager.current().connection
     val statement = conn.createStatement()
     val query = "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW someview"
     statement.execute(query)
}
```

Comment: Kiskae's answer is dead. The link returns 404

Comment: Should we close resources on me?
like that
```kotlin
executeQuery.close()
statement.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Outdated answer. `createStatement()` doesn't exist on `exposed 0.31.1`.

Comment: @Hykilpikonna the reason for this is because the `connection` field does not expose the JDBC connection directly, as a workaround (for anyone that *needs* the JDBC connection itself) you can do this: `val conn = (TransactionManager.current().connection as JdbcConnectionImpl).connection`

Answer (score 7):

Here an example with parameters:

```
transaction(database) {
   val conn = TransactionManager.current().connection
   val query = "update user set name = ? where id = ?";
   val statement = conn.prepareStatement(query, false)
   statement.fillParameters(listOf(Pair(VarCharColumnType(), "Laura"),
      Pair(IntegerColumnType(), 3)));
   statement.executeUpdate()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.sql.*
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.*
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.*

fun getAccId(db : Database, acc_domain: String) {
  transaction(db) {
    addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)
    var acc_id: Long = 0
    exec("select id from accounts where domain = '${acc_domain}'") { rs ->
        while(rs.next()) {
          acc_id = rs.getLong("id")
        }
    }
    println("Acc Id is ${acc_id}")
  }
}

val database = Database.connect(datasource)
getAccId(database,"mytest.test.io")
```

Comment: This method is prone to SQL injection and one should use prepared statement instead. See @Martin Pabst answer

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple helper function like:

```kotlin
fun <T : Any> String.execAndMap(transform: (ResultSet) -> T): List<T> {
    val result = arrayListOf<T>()
    TransactionManager.current().exec(this) { rs ->
        while (rs.next()) {
            result += transform(rs)
        }
    }
    return result
}
"select u.name, c.name from user u inner join city c where blah blah".execAndMap { rs ->
    rs.getString("u.name") to rs.getString("c.name")
}
```

Taken from: https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/FAQ#q-is-it-possible-to-use-native-sql--sql-as-a-string