# Spring Boot Kotlin Exposed Stored Procedure

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, stored-procedures, kotlin-exposed

is it posible to call stored procedure from Exposed and map result to object? I'am using Spring Boot with MS SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. You can use a transaction and run your own sql statement in it (calling the procedure) and create a mapping function for that object, where you map the fields of the result set to the ones of the object.

e: you can have a look in here, how to call simple sql statement and map the resultset

[Is there a way to run raw sql with Kotlin's Exposed library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981804/is-there-a-way-to-run-raw-sql-with-kotlins-exposed-library)