# How to insert and return an inserted row in Exposed?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have a code that inserts a new row and returns its ID:

```
transaction {
    val id = Comments.insert {
        it[this.postId] = postId
        it[msg] = comment.msg
        it[this.createdBy] = createdBy
    } get Comments.id
}
```

However, how can I return all values, not just ID? In SQL I would write a something as below:

```
INSERT INTO comments (post_id, msg, created_by)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
RETURNING id, post_id, msg, created_by, created_at;
```

Comment: @МихаилНафталь yeah, this is that I need! Thank you! It's little weird that I could not find that topic in Google.

Answer (score 4):

Specifying custom `RETURNING` clause is currently not supported by Exposed DSL.

There are some workarounds in this issue:
https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/1271

If you're willing to run native SQLs, then here's how:
[Is there a way to run raw sql with Kotlin's Exposed library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981804/is-there-a-way-to-run-raw-sql-with-kotlins-exposed-library)